# Creación de rutas personalizadas en el navegador asp.net MVC 4 ASPX c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, seguridad

Eh visto paginas web que sus rutas cambian o las esconden para tener mayor seguridad 
que por default vienen asi :

> Http:Localhost/Prueba/Index.html

Yo que se vea, aproximadamente así

> Http//Localhost/

o cambiar la ruta :

> **Http//Localhost/#q=como+esconder+la+url+de+mis+paginas**

¿Que librerias usan? ¿Tienen un pequeño ejemplo que me puedan pasar?

Comment: No puedes "esconder" la URL que ve el navegador. Si siempre envías la misma URL el servidor siempre devolverá la misma respuesta; si siempre envías la misma URL con distintos parámetros POST (por ejemplo) para poder decidir en el servidor que mostrar, simplemente ocultas a la vista, pero sigue siendo "visible". Sea lo que sea que envié el cliente es completamente visible para quien lo envía. [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) suele considerarse una mala práctica y no es la filosofía de la web.

Answer (score 3):

En ASP.NET puedes configurar las URLs de un sitio web a través de las características de enrutamiento.

En WebForms por defecto se utilizan rutas a los archivos físicos (aspx) mientras que si estás utilizando ASP.NET MVC por defecto utilizará rutas del tipo http://host/{controller}/{action}/{id}, donde controller es el nombre del controlador a ejecutar, action el nombre de la acción dentro del controlador e id es un valor opcional que puedes pasar a la acción.

Está configuración de rutas puede modificarse desde el evento Application_Start del archivo Global.asax añadiendo o modificando configuraciones de rutas a la colección RouteTable.Routes.

Puedes encontrar información sobre el enrutamiento en ASP.NET en la documentación de MSDN:

[Enrutamiento de ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)